# what are advaitin's established arguments against yoga school of Patanjali?

Tags: advaita, yoga, yoga-sutras, raja-yoga

the only weakness I know is that since Patanjali subscribes to samkhya, his philosophy also inherites the same weakness of samkhya,

a potential follow up conclusion would be "if yoga philosophy has defects then any advaitin should not practice yoga as described in yoga sutras"

please correct my understanding

hence my question